word-break:break-all for jqxgrid column headers
var CreatedTABLETGrid = function (catid) {

var columns =
    [

        { text: 'Integrator/Online/Business Partner', datafield: 'StockRange', columntype: 'textbox', filtercondition: 'contains', width: '3%', cellclassname: 'stockcolumns' }
    ];

var gridData = generatedata();
var source =
{
    totalrecords: gridData.length,
    localData: gridData,
    datafields:
        [
    
            { name: 'StockRange', type: 'string' },
   
        ],
    datatype: "array"
};
var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);    
$("#ProductPriceList").jqxGrid(
    {
       
        theme: "ui-redmond",
        width: '100%',
        autoheight: true,
        source: dataAdapter,
        columnsresize: true,
        groupable: true,
        sortable: true,
        showfilterrow: true,
        filterable: true,
        autoshowfiltericon: true,
        selectionmode: 'multiplecellsextended',
        columns:columns
        
       
    });}

I have this ProductPriceList grid. I want to apply word-break to the header of the columns. I tried to apply custom CSS below :
#columntableProductPriceList {
    word-wrap: break-word !important;
    /* IE 5.5+ and CSS3 */
    white-space: normal !important;
    /*height: auto !important;*/
    vertical-align: text-top !important;
    padding-top: 2px !important;
    padding-bottom: 3px !important;
}

But this didn't work, especially, using height: auto !important; doesn't show any text in the header.
Thanks in advance.

jqxgrid don't support warpped text in column header. The only way to do so is to setup your own rules to detect some changes for example: $("#ProductPriceList").on('columnresized', function (event) { ... }. Then you need to calculate the new height for different <div>. Finally update the new height to <div> and refresh the jqxgrid. I personally don't suggest you to use it, because just a little inappropriate setup can cause bugs and other unexpected display issue. Unless you know what you're doing.
Example: https://jsfiddle.net/u8r5632g/ (You need to modify it to fit your case!)
html code:
<div id="ProductPriceList"></div>

css code:
#ProductPriceList .jqx-grid-column-header {
    height: auto !important;
    white-space: normal !important;
    word-break: break-all !important;
}

JavaScript + jQuery code:
$(document).ready(function () {
    function updateColumnTableHeight() {
        var headerHeight = $('#ProductPriceList .jqx-grid-column-header').outerHeight();
        
        $('#columntableProductPriceList').height(headerHeight);
        
        // Select all elements with the specified class
        var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.jqx-widget-header.jqx-widget-header-ui-redmond.jqx-grid-header.jqx-grid-header-ui-redmond');
        // Loop through the NodeList and set the height for each element
        elements.forEach(function(element) {
            element.style.height = headerHeight+36+'px'; //+36 because of filter search input field
        });
    }

    // Data fields and columns definitions
    var columns = [
        { text: 'Integrator/Online/Business Partner', datafield: 'StockRange', columntype: 'textbox', filtercondition: 'contains', width: '10%', cellclassname: 'stockcolumns' }
    ];

    var gridData = generatedata();

    var source = {
        totalrecords: gridData.length,
        localData: gridData,
        datafields: [
            { name: 'StockRange', type: 'string' }
        ],
        datatype: "array"
    };

    var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);

    // Initialize jqxGrid with settings
    $("#ProductPriceList").jqxGrid({
        theme: "ui-redmond",
        width: '100%',
        //autoheight: true,
        
        autorowheight: true,
        autoheight: true,
        height: 500,
        
        source: dataAdapter,
        columnsresize: true,
        groupable: true,
        sortable: true,
        showfilterrow: true,
        filterable: true,
        autoshowfiltericon: true,
        selectionmode: 'multiplecellsextended',
        columns: columns
    });
    
    $("#ProductPriceList").on('columnresized', function (event) {
        updateColumnTableHeight();
        $(this).jqxGrid('refresh');
    });
    
    async function funcRetrieve() {
        // Wait for the grid to be fully loaded before calling updateColumnTableHeight()
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 400));
        updateColumnTableHeight();
        $(this).jqxGrid('refresh');
    };
    
    funcRetrieve();
});



couldn't make this work for my case :( but thank you, your demo looks exactly what I wanted
